# C# dynamically loaded files gets locked if debug information is used

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I load cs files dynamically using the following code:

```
CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
//add referenced assemblies
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(...);
//filePath is a constant path.
parameters.OutputAssembly = filePath + ".dll";
CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, loadedFile);
if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
{
     //error reporting
     return;
}
else
{
     //success reporting
}
byte[] assemblyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(results.PathToAssembly);
Assembly AssemblyReference = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
Type CompiledClass = AssemblyReference.GetType(/*some class in code*/);
InvokeStringMethod(CompiledClass, "Do_things", new object[] { /*some objects*/ });
```

This happens at a click of a button, and when clicking multiple times, files is compiled successfully and the method is called.

However when adding `parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;` to compiler parameters, the file is compiled successfully at the first time. but if I try to compile it again, the following error occurs:

`"Unexpected error creating debug information file '<filepath>\\AAA.PDB' -- '<filepath>\\AAA.pdb: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."`

I searched for this issue and found this solution:
[runtime code compilation gives error - process cannot access the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651293/runtime-code-compilation-gives-error-process-cannot-access-the-file) .However, if loading the files locks it, why doesn't this issue happen when not including debug information? shouldn't this be happening in all cases ?

Comment: Is a pdb created at all if you set `IncludeDebugInformation` to `false`?

Comment: no but aren't you essentially accessing the same `.dll` file ?

Comment: from the answer on the linked question I gathered that only the .pdb file was locked. Thus if it's only being created when that property is set to `true` it would explain why you don't get any problems when you set the property to `false`. If no file is being created, no file is being locked ;)

Answer (score 0):

The question you linked to [already has two answers by Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26699609/184528). What worked for me is to not assign to `parameters.OutputAssembly`.